# Microsoft Authentication Library(MSAL) not working with PNPJS to create SharePoint List Item

Tags: sharepoint, azure-ad-msal, spfx

Using below article we should be able to perform access & update SharePoint data.
[Calling SharePoint via MSAL](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/authentication/msaljsclient/#calling-sharepoint-via-msal)

But currently we can only access the data but not able to update/write data to SharePoint list.
Here is the code snippet which we are using in our solution.

```
import { MsalClientSetup  } from "@pnp/msaljsclient";
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

sp.setup({
sp: {
    baseUrl: "https://{my tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/",
    fetchClientFactory: MsalClientSetup({
        auth: {
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytentant.onmicrosoft.com/",
        clientId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        redirectUri: "https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/test.aspx",
         },
     }, ["https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/.default"]),
 },
});
const r = await sp.web();

//create list item
await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('FoodOrder')
  .items
  .add({
    Title: 'Chicken Fry',
    Quantity: 5,
    Remarks: 'Extra Spicy'
  })
 .then(async results => {
   console.dir(results);
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.error(err.message);
 });
```

Below are the permissions granted through Azure APP.
[image]

When we are trying to create/update item in SharePoint list it throws the below error.

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

It will be great helpful if any one have solution for this. Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you need to allow your application to write to the lists. Just give it permission to do so (you need AllSites.Write). The ClientId should not be "0000000000-00....", it should be your app id, the id of the app to which you give the permissions. "0000-..." is just a placeholder.

[image]

Like the documentation says:

> When calling the graph API you must specify the scopes you need and
> **ensure they are configured in AAD**

So basically you should do just that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2

Comment: Yes I have added the correct ClientID but for security reasons I have masked in above question. 
Also I have granted/configured all 4 permissions which is related to SharePoint operations(AllSites.FullControl, AllSites.Manage, AllSites.Read, AllSites.Write) and same updated on question.

Has the PnPjs with MSAL working for you to create item in SharePoint? 
Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm personally not using MSAL library (i'm using single-sign-on in Teams), in this case the permissions work just fine if you set them (for SharePoint, that is). Means, I'm just calling AzureAD rest endpoint directly. You can try to debug it by looking at the token you get and the scopes it has: just paste it to https://jwt.io, it can decode sharepoint tokens just fine.

Comment: One more thought - maybe old permissions are in effect? Try removing your app consents from the EnterpriseApplications, and get a new consent. You should see application asking for "write" directly in the consent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/delete-application-portal, clear browser caches (including appdata)

Comment: I have followed the above steps to clean the permission using EnterpriseApplications and tried but not working and same error getting.

Just doubt does the MSAL gives the option to delegate any kind of permission or only read-only permission as we see all the MS articles and other bloggers explained only reading user profile information or mails from user mailbox. I didn't find any MS documentation for writing/posting data using MSAL.

Comment: I think if you get authenticated at all using MSAL, that means MSAL is working, it must be a configuration issue then. Check my previous comments - inspect the token, reset the app, clear consents.